# why should we minimize the use of break and continue in loops?

Tags: c++, c

When I was a freshman, our instructor allowed us to use `break` or `continue` in loops. I did it most of the time back then since it terminates/continues the loop. And now I'm in sophomore years, my instructor told me that the use of `break`/`continue` is not advisable. Can you tell me why? What affects break/continue by the way?

Comment: Can't *he* tell you why?  Isn't that what he's there for?

Comment: First they came for `goto`, and I did not speak up, because I didn't use `goto`. Then they came for `continue` and `break`, and I did not speak up because I was avoiding loops at the time. Then they came for me...

Comment: :)  "Political correctness gone mad"

Comment: You can often turn a continue into an if statement.

Comment: As a person who has written over a million lines of c++ code I still use break and continue in loops. However I certainly do not do this most of the time. If I had to guess I would say its more like 1 out of 100 loops.

Answer (score 19):

Some people think that it's bad to have a too complex control flow, which means things like `break`, `continue` and multiple `return`s. The reason is not technical, but mostly that complex control flow can make it harder to verify, test and and reason about a program.

It is however largely a matter of style, personal taste, and your overall structure. With small, well-purposed functions, there might be little to no harm in having multiple possible flows. In C++ in particular, early exit is a popular idiom and can often make code easier to follow.

Comment: *In C++ in particular, early exit is a popular idiom and can often make code easier to follow.* And a C++ program can have very complex flow even if there's only one `return` statement: many destructors can run after that. Not to mention exceptions. But, like everything, use it in moderation.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Well, yes, that's the point: C++ *supports* early exits in the language. I think the OP's advice was mostly applied to C. I think the MISRA C rules mandate single returns, for example.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, Rule 14.7, *Only one exit point should be defined in a function*

Comment: @ta.speot.is I don't know where you get that from.  I've been programming C++ for over 25 years, and I've never used a `break` or a `continue` in a loop (and even less a `return`).  As Kerrek says, it makes reasoning about the correctness of the code significantly harder.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I’m working on a code base that follows this style guide and I find three layers of `if` statements and assignments to `result` variables much more confusing than just `return`.

Answer (score 5):

At least in C, you should not be using `break` and/or `continue` *"most of the time"* (as your question says you used to do) to control the flow of your loops. Your loop condition should indicate under what circumstances the loop should stop; somebody maintaining your code should not have to dig through the code in the body of your loop to see what triggers the `break` that causes the loop to stop.

For example, let's say you want to read a number of integers from a file `inputFile` to see if one of the integers is 500. One way of structuring the loop is:

```
while (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), inputFile)){
    sscanf (buffer, "%d", &num);
    if (num == 500)
       break;
}
```

Here, the person reading your code has to read your entire `while` loop to figure out what you are actually looking for in the file. If you write this without the `break`:

```
while ((num != 500) && fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), inputFile)) 
    sscanf (buffer, "%d", &num);
```

the loop condition itself tells the reader exactly what your code is trying to do, which makes it a lot more easy to understand quickly. Also, as a bonus, you have saved a few lines of code.

Now imagine a more complicated `while` or `for` loop, where the `break` is buried deep inside the body of the loop. It's easy to see why trying to find the `break` trigger would get annoying. Having a properly structured loop condition is much more, um, self-documenting.

There are, of course, cases where `break` and `continue` are in fact good ways to write the code. For example, if the condition at which the loop should end might occur in the middle of the loop execution, and there's a long set of statements that follow inside the loop, and executing those statements would add processing time without accomplishing anything useful, sure, go ahead and use the `break`. But those cases are the exception, not the "most of the time".

Comment: Would the downvoter honor me with an explanation?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think your point is quite mute: you exchange one evil (a `break`) for another (an over complicated loop condition). To me, the first version speaks more clearly, I think, it's the way to go with one basic loop condition, and another, abnormal condition that makes further processing obsolete. Even more so, because syntax highlighting readily lights up any `break` or `continue` statement. Anyway, I think you should avoid writing loops in which you would not be able to immediately spot a `break`.

Comment: @cmaster Thanks. I agree with you about an "abnormal condition" requiring a `break`, but in the admittedly artificial example here the *searched-for* result is `num == 500`. It's why the file is being read in the first place.  Expressed in plain English, the condition would be: "Look to see if the number 500 is in the file." I think the loop condition represents that logic more clearly. And I don't find it overcomplicated--natch. The basic point is, the logic of one's code should be easy to follow, and `break`s can obscure it, particularly if used "most of the time".

Comment: Well, I agree with you about that "most of the time" part :-) I just fail to see `break` as an evil in itself...

Answer (score 5):

Most of the logic I've seen for reasoning about code correctness
supposes single entry/single exit.  If your loops are filled
with `break` and `continue`, it becomes impossible to know
whether your loop invariants are met, or whether you always make
progress (so the loop won't be endless).  (Note that the `do
{ ... } while (...);` loop also suffers from this; the loop
invariants aren't established the first time through, which can
lead to some surprises.)

Most of the cases where you are tempted to use `break` or
`continue`, you've probably made the loop (and the function
which contains it) too large and too complex.

Some would argue that something like:

```
for (;;) {
    //  ...
    if ( conditionMet ) {
        break;
    }
    //  ...
}
```

would be acceptable for the classical loop and a half idiom; it
is single entry/single exit, after all, even if the exit isn't
quite where we expect it (and is very hard to find when reading
the code).  The problem concerning loop invariants remains; the
aren't met before the `if`, at least the first time through.
Generally, a better solution would be to put the code before the
test into a separate function, which returns `conditionMet`, and
use:

```
while ( doLoopPrefix() ) {
    doLoopSuffix();
}
```

(In general, if your loop is more than three or four lines, you
should refactor.  Except maybe if it contains a single `switch`
statement, with a lot of cases.)